# emergency aid.The file I saved in the LaTeX program is missing

Tags: files

The file I saved in the LaTeX program is missing. How can I bring back what I write.

Comment: latex does not have any way to save files, it just takes input and generates typeset output. You presumably wrote the file in an editor, which may have a backup facility but without knowing which editor you use impossible to say anything.

Comment: I saved the file but the LaTeX page did not appear on the screen. There are no files I have recorded.

Comment: it would be a nice help, if you could state what program you're using.

Comment: @gmz: A paranoid backup strategy sounds weird but saves you a lot of time ;-)

Comment: ı use TEX.studio @naphaneal

Comment: first look using the filemanager at the folder, is the `.tex` file there, or any backup (really any file you work on should be in a source control or backed up on a different machine) but editors do not delete files for no reason, if you had a file and haven't deleted it most likely it is there still

Comment: Normally, TeXstudio has `autosave` files every  5 min.

Comment: autosave on TeXstudio is off by default. Exactly what files are missing?

Comment: I made a presentation in the Tex (beamer) file. After the page was saved, the page disappeared.

Comment: @gmz: What do you mean by page?